# Using join on same table three times

Tags: c#, linq

I am using join on same table three times:

```
var queryResults = from avse in agreementVacationApplicationDomainContext.AVSEs
                   join utyp in agreementVacationApplicationDomainContext.UTYPs on avse.UTYPId equals utyp.Id
                   join ktabAgreement in agreementVacationApplicationDomainContext.KTABs on avse.KtabAVTALId equals ktabAgreement.Id
                   join ktabVacation in agreementVacationApplicationDomainContext.KTABs on avse.KTABVacationGroupId equals ktabVacation.Id
                   join ktab in agreementVacationApplicationDomainContext.KTABs on avse.KTABId equals ktab.Id
                   where ktab.KTABTOM >= DateTime.Today
                   select new
                   {
                       avse.Id,
                       ktabId = ktab.Id,
                       ktabVacationId = ktabVacation.Id,
                       ktabAgreementId = ktabAgreement.Id,
                       utypId = utyp.Id,
                       EmployementAgreement = ktabAgreement.KTABINIT + " " + ktabAgreement.KTXTLANG,
                       VacationGroup = ktabVacation.KTABINIT + " " + ktabVacation.KTXTLANG,
                       KtabCode = ktab.KTABINIT + " " + ktab.KTXTLANG,
                       FieldName = utyp.UPPGTYP
                   };
```

Is there a better way to implement this query?

Answer (score 2):

Yes: don't use joins, but use navigation properties. Instead of

```
join utyp in agreementVacationApplicationDomainContext.UTYPs on avse.UTYPId equals utyp.Id
```

You should probably just use `avse.UTYP` (which will be equivalent to `utyp` in your original query). This is still a join under the covers, but automatic. If you correctly map your model, navigation properties like this are available.

The number of cases where you need to use a join with an ORM and LINQ is vanishingly small because most table relationships are available as navigation properties.

Comment: True but then how will I get different records for three different values.

Comment: You can use navigation properties in queries as well. Delete the  join and use the property instead.